# Remove a table row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append some rows in my table. Now I want to remove a row by clicking on a button inside of that row. My append logic works but I cannot make my remove logic work.

**HTML**:

```
<table style="background-color:#ffe6e6;width:50%;">

                <tr><th colspan="6" style="border-bottom:1px solid #AAAAAA;">Credits</th></tr>

                <tr><th>User</th><th>Account</th><th>Item</th><th>Unit Price</th> <th>Quantity</th><th>Amount</th></tr>
                <tr id="student_entry">
                <td>

                    <select name="account" class="form-control" required style="width: 100px;">
                       <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_account');?></option>
                          <?php 
                             $categories = $this->db->get_where('account', array('category1' => 'EXPENSE'))->result_array();
                             foreach ($categories as $row):
                             ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $row['componentId'];?>"><?php echo $row['description'];?></option>
                       <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="item_selector_holder" name="item[]" class="form-control" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 0px;">
                    <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_item');?></option>
                    <?php $categories = $this->db->get('item')->result_array();
                        foreach ($categories as $row):
                    ?>      
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['componentId'];?>"><?php echo $row['itemName'];?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" style="width: 80px;" name="unitPrice" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>"/>  
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" style="width: 80px;" name="unitPrice" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" style="width: 80px;"  name="quantity" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                <span style="margin-right: 0px; padding-left: 20px">
                    <input onclick="deleteParentElement();" type="button" style="width: 3px; font-weight: bold;font-size: large;" value="-"/>
                </span>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="student_entry_append2"></tr>
                <tr><th> <input onclick="append_credit_table_row();" type="button" style="padding: 3px 8px;font-weight: bold;font-size: large;" value=" + "/> </th><th colspan="3">Total</th><th id="ttlcr">0.00</th></tr>

            </table>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var blank_student_entry ='';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$('#bulk_add_form').hide(); 
        blank_student_entry = $('#student_entry').html();
        for ($i = 1; $i<1;$i++) {
            $("#student_entry").append(blank_student_entry);
        }

    });

    function append_credit_table_row()
    {
        $("#student_entry_append2").after('<tr>' +blank_student_entry +'</tr>');
    }

    // REMOVING INVOICE ENTRY
    function deleteParentElement()
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();

    }
</script>
```

Please can anyone help, or suggest a solution?

Comment: there's no reference to 'this' as in your input element. You need to pass it in. Make changes to these: `deleteParentElement(element)` and  `<input onclick="deleteParentElement(this);"` and $(element).parent().parent().parent().remove();

Comment: i want to delete the row in which button contains. how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive this using jQuery's [has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/) function.

```js
function deleteParentElement(item) {
   $("tr").has($(item)).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>                    <!-- important -->
        <input onclick="deleteParentElement(this);" type="button" value="delete1"/>
        This is a row 1
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>                    <!-- important -->
        <input onclick="deleteParentElement(this);" type="button" value="delete2"/>
        This is a row 2
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>                    <!-- important -->
        <input onclick="deleteParentElement(this);" type="button" value="delete3"/>
        This is a row 3
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>                    <!-- important -->
        <input onclick="deleteParentElement(this);" type="button" value="delete4"/>
        This is a row 4
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>                    <!-- important -->
        <input onclick="deleteParentElement(this);" type="button" value="delete5"/>
        This is a row 5
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>                    <!-- important -->
        <input onclick="deleteParentElement(this);" type="button" value="delete6"/>
        This is a row 6
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example of dynamically creating a table row with a button that can be clicked to remove the row.

The removal code locates the `target` of the `event` on the `click` handler and because the `<button>` is in a `<td>` (1) in a `<tr>` (2) you have to call `.parent()` twice.

Here's a stack snippet:

```js
var index = 0;

$('#test_add').on('click', function() {
  index += 1;
  var template_row = '<tr><td><button class="row_remove_btn">Remove</button></td><td>Foo' + index + '</td><td>Bar' + index + '</td></tr>';
  $('#t tbody').append(template_row);
});

$('#t').on('click', 'button.row_remove_btn', function(event) {
  var row = $(event.target).parent().parent();
  row.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="test_add">Add Row</button>

<table id="t">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```